# Remove comma from Email Intent (EXTRA_EMAIL)

Tags: android

I'm using an email intent within my Android app. It works fine, but when the email is ported to the email application it always adds a comma to the email address row.
I tried to add the email address with a string, but it only works with a string array. Is there a chance to remove that comma?

Here is my code:

```
String stremailaddress;
stremailaddress = "myemail@whatever.com";
String emailaddress[] = { stremailaddress };
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
```

This is how the email address row looks like in the email application:

```
myemail@whatever.com,
```

I want it to look like this:

```
myemail@whatever.com
```

Comment: Why do you need the comma removing? It shouldn't effect anything.

Comment: That's right, but it looks so "poor". It wouldn't matter if the user adds the email addresses manually, but this one should only add my email address automatically. That's why the comma is useless in this situation.Well, nevermind. It seems i have to live with it. Thanks to all for your fast help!

Answer (score 1):

You cant alter this behavior because the comma is inserted by the email app itself. Unless you have written your own email app to eradicate comma, you have to live with this. Though there's no harm in having a comma at the end because if the email app inserts it, then it may also take care of it before sending the mail.

The only reason that comma insertion is for your ease to add further email addresses manually. So, just ignore it if you don't want to add more addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the email application, and how it chooses to display the list of email addresses it receives. So, no, you can't do anything about it.

(And it doesn't matter anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does matter. All emails attempted from my phone returns a message that the email message could not be delivered.

Comment: This should be a comment, it does not answer the question.